# Issue retrieving hard-disk volumes

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

On my computer, I have following disk drives.

[image]

I only want to get list of hard-disk volumes, which in this case should be C and E. I have following script and its output.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select Name

Name
----
A:
C:
D:
E:
```

How can I get desried volumes in this case? I am using PS Version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter by `DriveType`. Type 3 = local disks.

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype = 3" | Select Name
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have the option to upgrade to PS Version 3 you can just use `get-psdrive` otherwise you can use the `where` command to filter it out to the desired results. For example:

`Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | where Name -eq "C:" | Select Name`

Also be mindful as to the order that you use `Select`/`Where` as this can impact the processing time for larger operations

Comment: script should detect which volumes are present. So in another machines it may have three hard disk partitions C,D, E. I don't think filtering by volumes names will help as we wouldn't know all volume names. That's what I am trying to find out

Comment: When you're looking for a list of things that may vary, it's impossible to hard-code a specific name, so filtering using `where Name -eq` clearly won't work.